# In-app purchase for physical goods - forbidden or not recommended?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-checkout, in-app-billing

Is selling of physical goods via Android in-app purchase forbidden or just not recommended?

I know that there is a problem with shipping, but one can easily make final price increased by shipping costs. What if there is not shipping cost?

Please share your experiences with me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a business question, not a technical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a quote from In-App Billing Overview from developer.android.com:

> You can use in-app billing to sell
>   only digital content. You cannot use
>   in-app billing to sell physical goods,
>   personal services, or anything that
>   requires physical delivery.

Comment: I know that line. They did it because of inability to handle shipping. What if a good does not have shipping cost?

Comment: I was hoping someone has already asked them as they are slow on reply.

Comment: doc with the quote : https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html

Answer (score 2):

I believe that in case of virtual goods there is no need to confirm that the good was received. Payment processed immedeatly and there is only little time to rollback it. In case of phisical goods, sell could be rolled back if good was nor delivered or it is of improper quality and so on.
So in principle you could agree to sell somethind using in-app payment, but google doesn't want to deal with it.

Comment: I am fine with that. Do you know if can Google ban, punish or something else if I use in-app billing for physical goods?

Answer (score 1):

[Another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7125804/334209) was asked a couple of months later. It says that a physical good can be sold using alternative payments method than Google's.

Comment: And your app won't be banned because you're using a non-Google in-app purchasing?

Comment: Well Google is not clear about that. I'm a bit concerned about a part of the TOU. More details in a question I've asked 2 days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923553/is-it-a-violation-of-android-terms-of-use-to-selling-physical-goods-with-third-p