# Purchases in Android

Tags: android, credit-card, billing, purchase-order

How are purchases of physical products handled in android? Are there any limitants and/or considerations? As I read in this article: 
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html
Android developers are only considering digital products not physical. Nevertheless,I just found an office depot app which let us choose physical products from their store, add them to a shopping car and check them out. Furthermore, when cheking out we also have the chance to add a payment account i.e. credit card, meaning we must use security either for storing credit card data or to send it. When working with  In-App, they say that the end-user makes his purchases by using its linked android market account (as well as the developer ..and a merchandise account also) but in the other case with office depot, I guess the developer must build the entire billing platform, doesn't he?

Answer (score 3):

> You can use in-app billing to sell only digital content. You **cannot**
> use in-app billing to sell physical goods, personal services, or
> anything that requires physical delivery.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html#billing-limitations)

Thats for googles in app-billing. You may use other payment methods (self-built or external such as paypal). <strike>But these are not allowed in the android market *afaik*. So you have to distribute your app yourself too, or use alternative markets.</strike>

---

Edit:

Oh found something:

> **Developers charging for applications and
> downloads from Android Market must do so by using an authorized
> Payment Processor.** Developers offering additional content, goods, or
> services for an application downloaded from Android Market must offer
> an authorized Payment Processor as the payment option.
>
> The following are **exceptions** for the two requirements above:
>
> - **Where payment is primarily for a physical good or service** (e.g. buying
>   movie tickets; e.g. buying a newspaper app where the price also
>   includes a hard copy subscription)
> - Where payment is for digital
>   content or goods that may be consumed outside of the application
>   itself (e.g. buying songs that can be played on other music players)

[Source](http://www.android.com/us/developer-content-policy.html)

So i was wrong. It seems to be allowed to use other payment providers if you are distributing physical goods.

Comment: If so then how is depot office app available in android market? I guess they really did all the billing platform and as it still accessible, there must be no restrictions further than lot's of code lines.

Comment: As said, as far as I know. But I'm not a lawyer. Maybe google didn't notice the app yet. Quotes from the TOS: *"4.5. You may not use the Market to distribute or make available any Product whose primary purpose is to facilitate the distribution of Products outside of the Market"*. Which sounds like what you are describing to me. See http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html

Comment: Thank you, alextsc. You've been of great help!

Comment: The issue with that line is that we don't really know what "authorized Payment Processor" means. Currently, only Google Wallet is an authorized payment processor: http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html